# 【Angular Material】How to place two <mat-tab-group> in the same horizontal, and one with mat-stretch-tabs directive

Tags: angular-material

How to build something like what you see on this picture?

[image]

This is what I have tried and is not correct:

```xml
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="A">
        A
    </mat-tab>
    <!--this is wrong-->
    <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
        <mat-tab label="A">
            A
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="A">
            A
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="A">
            A
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="A">
            A
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the nested mat-tab-group inside a mat-tab?

Comment: @Pipimi No, I want to have a Tab column similar to the picture example
But not nested <mat-tab-group>